# Perfect forwarding of this pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding

I have the following code:

```
template<typename T>
class Dispatcher
{
public:
    void operator()(T&& v) {}
};

struct S
{
    Dispatcher<S*> dispatcher;

    void test()
    {
        dispatcher(this);
    }
};
```

And it gives me an error `error C2664: 'void Dispatcher<S *>::operator ()(T &&)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'S *const ' to 'S *&&'` in **VisualStudio** only. In **gcc** and **clang** it works ok.

I searched the documentation and the only thing I found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) is: `When used according to the following recipe in a function template, forwards the argument to another function with the value category it had when passed to the calling function.`

Does that means perfect forwarding is guaranteed to work only with functions? Does **gcc** and **clang** are not following the standard?

Comment: Why are you linking to `std::forward` while your code does not contain it and you don' t really mention it?

Comment: @Holt I removed all the code and left only the minimal example that actually fails.

Comment: Still, you're not using forwarding. So how is the semantics of forwarding relevant?

Comment: Compiles fine on GCC: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/653cdea8e03919d8

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I thought if I'm using template argument together with `&&` it uses collapsing rules which are only useful with perfect forwarding.

Comment: @nikitablack Here `T` is a parameter of `Dispatcher`, not of its `operator()`. `T&&` is not a forwarding reference because `T` is not deduded.

Comment: @Quentin Just to be clear - reference collapsing rules work **only with templated function**, right?

Comment: @nikitablack Yep. And I did mean "deduced" :p